# Аналог zoom в css? Свойство transform: scale() как свойство zoom

Tags: javascript, css, transform, zoom, scale

В css есть свойство `zoom`, оно делает то, что нужно, но нет поддержки в браузерах (в частности Firefox).

Так же есть свойство `transform: scale()`, но дело в том, что блок `main_div` становится видимым при использовании `transform: scale()`, чего нет при использовании свойства `zoom`. Мне нужно именно такое поведение

Может свойство `transform: scale()` можно применить таким образом, чтобы он работал как `zoom`?

Или какие аналоги есть у свойства `zoom`?

Как быть в этой ситуации?

Здесь мой код. Проверять нужно в Google Chrome, т.к. в Firefox свойство zoom не работает.
https://jsfiddle.net/tj2349f5/1/

```js
let test_button = document.querySelector('input.test_button');
test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //second_div.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';
  second_div.style.zoom = 0.5;
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    display: flex;
}

div#main_div {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 80vw;
    background: red;
    overflow: scroll;
}


div#second_div {
    height: 3000px;
    width: 3000px;
    background: green;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_div'>
  <div id="second_div">Hello</div>
</div>
<input class="test_button" type="button" name="button_name" value="test">
```

Comment: `transform: scale()` и есть аналог `zoom`, но чтобы тебе помочь, ты должен описать, что именно ты хочешь получить в результате... Не понятно, чего ты хочешь добиться в результате

Comment: Ну в Chrome `zoom` ведет себя абсолютно одинаково с `transform:scale(0.5)`

Comment: @Air когда я использую transform: scale() и уменьшаю масштаб блока second_div (зеленый), блок main_div становится видимым (он красный), если прокрутить вперед, чего нет при использовании свойства zoom. Видимо свойство zoom блок second_div (зеленый) "правильно" редактирует (подгоняет). Вот мне нужно, чтобы блока main_div не было видно при уменьшении масштаба блока second_div.

Comment: @DiD посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой пример. Если изменять стили через JavaScript, то они даже в Chrome ведут себя не одинаково. Выше в комментарии я написал в чем разница, и чего именно я хочу получить.

Comment: @Air отдельное спасибо, что поправили мой вопрос. А как Вы изменили слова, чтобы они выделялись?

Comment: @Air у меня оба ведут себя одинаково и за зеленым идет красный только в том случае если я использую их оба одновременно.

Comment: @Air у меня расширение монитора 1360, если у Вас больше, то попробуйте, пожалуйста, увеличить размеры самого блока, например, с 3000 до 10000 или больше, или наоборот уменьшить.

Comment: При чем тут расширение?

Comment: @Manu, я разобрался, я вот только одного не понимаю, на кой хрен нужны эти scale zoom ? поставь нужный размер тебе `width:1500px;height:1500px;` если надо, уменьши `font-size: 0.5em;` если нужно, чтобы буквы уменьшились! Прост всё же решается прямой математикой, там же все равно javascript используешь же.

Comment: @Air Это как вариант. Я просто не понимаю, как Вы не видите разницы в моем примере https://jsfiddle.net/tj2349f5/1/

Comment: @Manu, разные версии браузера, на маке нет разницы, scale работает как zoom

Comment: @DiD Спасибо, но дело не в буквах. Буквы это просто как пример. А мне нужно, что бы блок second_div изменялся так же как и содержимое, но при его уменьшении не было видно блока main_div. Со свойством zoom такой результат достигается, но это свойство не стандартизировано, а самое главное в Firefox не поддерживается.

Comment: @Manu Так уменьшайте  содержимое вместе с блоком. scale как бы продолжает резервировать под себя место. zoom - это тоже не то что вам нужно, только по счастливой случайности у него похожий эффект. Это свойство нигде не работает не только в фаэрфоксе. Вам нужно сжать блок до нужного размера и так же как и блоку дать нужные размеры всему содержимому.

Comment: @DiD Т.е. как я понимаю, нужно руками уменьшить ширину и высоту блока, а содержимое уменьшать через scale? Или я что-то не так понял? Если Вам не сложно, можете на моем примере реализовать это

Comment: @Manu вы почти правильно меня поняли, кроме использования scale(). Руками править ширину и высоту и блока и каждого элемента его содержимого. Если содержимое содержит текст, то масштаб текста задается `font-size` в единицах `em`.

Comment: @DiD спасибо Вам и вообще всем, кто не остался равнодушным

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решил так

```js
let test_button = document.querySelector('input.test_button');
test_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  span.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

div#main_div {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div#second_div {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 3000px;
  background: green;
}

span {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.active {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id='main_div'>
  <div id="second_div"><span id="span">Hello</span></div>
</div>
<input class="test_button" type="button" name="button_name" value="test">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но нужно, чтобы блок second_div изменялся так же как и содержимое, но при его уменьшении не было видно блока main_div. Со свойством zoom такой результат достигается, но это свойство не стандартизировано, а самое главное в Firefox не поддерживается. Может быть можно как-то заставить transform: scale() вести себя таким образом?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать повесить `transform: scale(n)` на `body` и затем принудительно установить ширину `body` так, чтобы он вписался в область видимости окна.

Например, можно отмасштабировать таким образом в 2 раза:

```css
body {
  transform: scale(2);
  width: calc(100vw / 2);
}
```

Возможно, дополнительно потребуется добавить смещение:

```css
transform: scale(2) translateX(50vw);
```

Comment: Я отредактировал свой вопрос, и, возможно, сейчас будет понятнее чего я хочу. Просто, я не совсем понял Ваш совет, а точнее как именно им воспользоваться. Просто в основном коде есть шапка и остальное, а этот код просто для примера